# Need help identifying cable in old boombox

Tags: pcb, identification, antenna, radio

I'm planning to replace the radio part of my old boombox with a 3.5mm jack so I can connect my phone. The cable that leads from the main pcb to the radio pcb has four lines, labeled L, G, R and +B. I assume L is left, G is ground and r is right. But what is +B? Do I need it for the headphone jack?

Thanks.

Edit: [Here's a picture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PEZ2ca5JqxnlQUCJmdd5nwA_vcnzYveU)

Comment: Vbat =B+ "........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The +B is for the battery positive. You will not need it for the headphone jack. Most boomboxes have a headphone jack built in.

Comment: Alright thank you. Mine doesn't have one, else I wouldn't want to put one in it.